Tailwind styles not working in production with Next.js
I finished my portfolio using Next JS, tailwind css and when i tried deploying it to production using Vercel. it looked all broken as if the css doesn't work at all just like in the screenshot (everything is fine on localhost) and same thing when i tried deploying in netlify.
this is the github repo
Portfolio-v3
this is the portfolio in localhost

this is when deployed


i tried adding purge array instead of content in tailwind config like some posts here suggested but didnt work

Please include [mre] in your question. Posting debugging question with only an external link to code at here isn't enough. You can start with using the browser's developer tool and check what CSS classes are applied.

hey how did you fix this
